# How to "read" information from CSV file in a bash script

Tags: bash, csv

Hi I'm noob o Stack but in Bash too.

**I'm trying to write a script which should "read" from an csv file some data depending on a codnition.**

Example:

*If I have a **Name** col in csv file and another col for **Grades**, I would like to keep the **name** (in an array or variable) of those **who scored more than a 5 in Grade's col.***

My dude is "*how to read from this file and select the value to use it on my script*".

I know that I don't have to "read" anything like in C++, but I tryed to explain myself better I can.

Sorry for my english and thank you everyone for your time.

PD: I put excel but I meant csv, sorry for confusion.

Comment: `bash` and Excel do not make a happy couple. Consider converting the Excel file to CSV which can definitely work, or using Python to read an Excel file if you can't go to CSV.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Your title says “csv”, but you ask about Excel. So which format you would like to read?

Comment: So long as your data is exported in .csv format, you can read quite easily with either `read -d ',' name` followed by `read -d ',' column` (and then a `read foo` to read to the end-of-line). Perform your check and either add values to an array, or skip to the next. You can also use *process substitution* with `awk` to handle the read of the .csv in a single call. You have many options.

Comment: `awk -F , ´$2 > 5' file.csv`

Comment: There's a potential stumbling block with CSV, which is that CSV uses an escape syntax to represent newline, comma, and quotes in the data. `awk` and other typical unix tools do not process the escape syntax, meaning they can make mistakes with the field interpretation. Check the contents of the file. If it contains CSV escapes, either export in TSV (tab-separated) or use a "csv2tsv" converter to remove the escapes and set TAB as the field delimiter. Then use the TAB character as the delimiter.